# Java Parameter Index Out Of Range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java

i have the following function:

```
public void updateItem(String id, String name, String quantity, String price){
    String query = "UPDATE items SET name = '?', price = ?, quantity = ? WHERE id = ?";
    try(PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query)){
        st.setString(1, name);
        st.setString(2, quantity);
        st.setString(3, price);
        st.setString(4, id);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Updated");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

but whenever i try to run it it gives me the following error:

```
Parameter Index Out Of Range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)
```

I was reading about this error and it has something to do with the question marks but i'm not sure where exactly the error is. If someone can help me out I would really appreciate it.

This is my second post so sorry if this isn't correct in some way.

Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Why do some of your placeholders have `'` while the others don't?

Comment: If i take out the single quotes and try to run it MySql gives me th following error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'My Name' in 'field list'`

Comment: Can you show us the implementation or at least info you are given about `PreparedStatement.setString`?

Comment: It's working now. I just needed to actually execute the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two changes (that I can see),

```
name = '?'
```

should be

```
name = ?
```

And, you aren't actually executing your statement in your posted code.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that. Yeah I was missing the execute on the query. Thanks again :D.